# Extract unique values and number of occurrences of each value from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract the number of each unique entry from one dataframe column and store it as a new dataframe, something like this:

**Input**

```
sample_name
    sample1
    sample2
    sample2
    sample3
    sample3
    sample3
```

**Desired output**

```
sample_name  count
    sample1      1
    sample2      2
    sample3      3
```

**Edit**
I'm guessing this is getting downvoted for not showing what I've tried, so for other users who might find themselves in the same situation, here's where I stagnated:

Given the input-dataframe, I was able to extract the unique entries:

```
input_df["sample_name"].unique()  # ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3']
```

And the number of occurences (not per unique entry):

```
input_df.groupby("sample_name")["sample_name"].transform("count")
```

which outputs

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
```

What I didn't figure out was how to extract the counts per unique entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [142]:
df['sample_name'].value_counts()

Out[142]:
    sample3    3
    sample2    2
    sample1    1
Name: sample_name, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in python with the invaluable Counter class in the collections module:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(df['sample_name'])
```

Which will return a dictionary with sample_name keys and occurence counts as values.